# How to remove duplicates elements in nested list in c++

Tags: c++, list, nested-lists

I'm trying to solve one np-complete problem in C++. I can solve this problem in Python but running time is relatively slow, so that's why I switch to C++. In one part of the problem I need to clean duplicate elements from my list.

I have a list the type is list<list<int> > in c++. My list contains duplicate elements for example:

If I send list below as an input:

```
[ [1,2,3] , [2,3,4] , [2,3,4] , [4,5,6] ]
```

I should get `[ [1,2,3] , [2,3,4] , [4,5,6] ]` as a result from the method.

So, how can I make my nested list contains only unique elements? Are there any efficient way or built-int function in c++ instead of using nested loop?

Comment: isn't this just `std::unique`?

Comment: std:unique isn't work because this is nested list.

Comment: `unique` should work as long as the outer list is sorted. You might need to define a predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this solution is not rational, but I offer to use `set<list<int>>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
template<class Type>
void showContentContainer(Type& input)
{
    for(auto itemSet : input)
    {
        for(auto iteratorList=itemSet.begin(); iteratorList!=itemSet.end(); ++iteratorList)
        {
            cout<<*iteratorList<<", ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return;
}
void solve()
{
    list<list<int>> listOfLists={{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6}};
    set<list<int>> setOfLists;
    for(auto iterator=listOfLists.begin(); iterator!=listOfLists.end(); ++iterator)
    {
        setOfLists.insert(*iterator);
    }
    cout<<"Before, listOfLists <- "<<endl;
    showContentContainer(listOfLists);
    listOfLists.clear();
    for(auto item : setOfLists)
    {
        listOfLists.push_back(item);
    }
    cout<<endl<<"After, listOfLists <- "<<endl;
    showContentContainer(listOfLists);
    cout<<endl;
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
Before, listOfLists <- 
1, 2, 3, 
2, 3, 4, 
2, 3, 4, 
4, 5, 6, 

After, listOfLists <- 
1, 2, 3, 
2, 3, 4, 
4, 5, 6,
```

Comment: Not as elegant and simple as the `unique` solution, but using a set is quite logical here. Just two comments on your solution: 1) you could have used another range-based for loop for your inner loop in `showContentContainer`; and 2) you can create a container from a begin and an end iterator from another container: https://godbolt.org/z/zj6ehbEP9

Comment: Maybe I should say: 3) try not to `use namespace std;`, and 4) prefer `\n` to `std::endl`: https://godbolt.org/z/To7aecYfM

Comment: @rturrado, I agree. You are right.

Answer (score 2):

`std::unique` works just fine: (where `input` is your nested list)

```
auto it = std::unique(begin(input), end(input));
input.erase(it, end(input));
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't eliminate any element.

Comment: @wheneverr Sort the lists.

Comment: My lists are sorted like an example in the post.

Comment: @wheneverr Works for me: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v4rbfEY8d